# How to link a dropdownlist and table data to change data on selected item on same id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I select an item in a dropdownlist, I want my table to refresh data on same id. As you can see, I want my table 1 in a dropdownlist and table 2 in a table-like grid

[image]

So when I pick from table 1 id 1, my grid will refresh data on foreign key 1, and when I pick from table 1 id 2, my grid will refresh data on foreign key 2, etc.

Comment: Please some time reading the [help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to understand how to ask a question here.

Comment: you first study about mvc and linq then ask question if have a problem .

Comment: sorry, i post first time, i read all posts and still don't know how to solve it. I'll read help files for future how to describe problem better, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:  This is a fairly common problem that all new developers to MVC will encounter.  I have updated my answer to include a complete working example on how to solve this.  I suspect it will help other new comers in the future.**.

You will need to accomplish this with some JavaScript (JQuery) and another action on a controller that will return your list of related items based on the id selected OR you could have the child action return a partial view with the select list data.

Your first task is to wire up an event in script to the .change() event on your first drop down list.

Once you have that captured - you can post the id to other action and have it return your data or partial view.

Solution

Cascading drop downs in MVC are accomplished through a combination of a few techniques.  You need view models to render the drop downs (select lists) and you will need some JavaScript code to capture events on the client browser and get additional data.  Finally you will use a partial view to return back to the client.

In this example - we are going to create a Select List with 3 parent values in it.  When a user selects a different value, we will request a new second drop down list corresponding to the parent values.

1. I created simple model classes

   ```
   public class Catalog
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime CatalogDate { get; set; }
   }

   public class Book
   {
       public int BookId { get; set; }
       public int CatalogId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public decimal Price { get; set; }

    }

   public class CatalogViewModel
   {
       public int SelectedCatalog { get; set; }

       public List<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }

   }

   public class BookViewModel
   {
       public int SelectedBook { get; set; }
       public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
   }
   ```

The catalog and book view models will be used in our Razor views with an DropDownListFor HTML helper.  The SelectedCatalog and SelectedBook properties hold the actual selected value - while the Catalogs and Books properties are used to load the Select Lists.

2. On the Index action of the Home controller - I modified the method:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {

       CatalogViewModel model = new CatalogViewModel()
       {
           Catalogs = Catalogs(),
       };
       return View(model);
   }
   ```

Here will will return a list of catalogs in the CatalogViewModel.

3. I also added in a another action that we will use for the Ajax call:

   ```
   public ActionResult Books(string catalogId)
   {
       int catId = Convert.ToInt32(catalogId);
       var model = new BookViewModel()
       {
           Books = Books().Where(x => x.CatalogId == catId).ToList()
       };
       return PartialView("Partials/_BooksDropDownList", model);
   }
   ```

This method will accept the catalog Id specified by the user and retrieve a list of books corresponding the catalog id. This will then be used in a partial view and returned to the caller.

4. The Index view of the Home controller:

   ```
     @model WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.CatalogViewModel

     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCatalog, new SelectList(Model.Catalogs, "Id", "Name"))

     <div id="bookContainer"></div>

   <script>

       $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#SelectedCatalog').change(function () {
           CatalogChanged();
       });
    });


   function CatalogChanged() {
       var catalogId = $('#SelectedCatalog').val();

       $.get('@Url.Action("Books","Home")' + "?catalogId=" + catalogId,
           function (data) {
               $('#bookContainer').html(data);
           });
   }
   ```

Here we have the model defined, an Html helper that renders our first Drop Down List, an empty containing div to hold the second drop down list and some script.

The script is simply capturing the .change event of the drop down list and calling the CatalogChanged function.  In this function, we get the value of the drop down list and issue a get request using a Url helper to construct the url back to the Home/books action.

5. Here is the partial view loaded dynamically based on the selected value from the first drop down.

   ```
    @model WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.BookViewModel

    <div id="BookDropDown">

           @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedBook, new SelectList(Model.Books, "BookId", "Name"))

     </div>
   ```

That's it.  This is a fairly common way of solving this type of problem. There are other ways (like using data and generating the html from script).

I wrote this out because it can be overwhelming getting started and hopefully this will help someone else out down the road.

Comment: okay, thank you, i'll keep searching in that way.